# Show only one form field on Edit select in iteration with React and Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, edit, semantic-ui-react

I'm iterating through notes in a React component.

If the user wants to edit a note, I'd like to replace the note text with an input field, populate it with the current text value, `handleChange`, and only show the input field for that particular entry.

Right now it changes all of the entries because it's within the iteration in the component.
I'm using Semantic-ui-react.

Here's an image of the undesired results after the user clicks the edit icon:

[image: Image of update forms]

My component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Comment, Table, Form, Button, Icon, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { createNote } from "../actions/createNoteAction";
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");
class ServiceLogsComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        entry: "",
        showInput: false
    }

  
    handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const userId = 2;
        this.props.createNote(this.state.entry, this.props.serviceId, userId)
        this.setState({ entry: "" })
    }

    handleUpdate = e => {
        this.setState({ showInput: true })
     
    }

    filterNotes = () => {
        const filteredNotes = this.props.notes.filter(note => note.service_id === this.props.serviceId)
        return filteredNotes
    }

    render() {
    console.log(this.state) 
     return (
       <>
         <div style={{ display: this.props.showServiceLogs }}>
           <Table>
             <Table.Body>
               <Comment>
                 <Comment.Group>
                   {this.filterNotes().map((serviceNote) => (
                     <Comment.Content>
                       <Table.Row key={uuidv4}>
                         <Table.Cell>
                           <Comment.Author as="a">
                             {serviceNote.created_at}
                           </Comment.Author>
                         </Table.Cell>
                         <Table.Cell>
                           <Comment.Metadata>
                             {serviceNote.user.username}
                           </Comment.Metadata>
                         </Table.Cell>
                         {serviceNote.user.id !== 1 ? (
                           <Table.Cell>
                             <Icon
                               name="edit outline"
                               onClick={(e) => this.handleUpdate(e)}
                             />
                             <Icon name="delete" />
                           </Table.Cell>
                         ) : null}
                       </Table.Row>
                       <Table.Row>
                         <Table.Cell>
                             {!this.state.showInput ? 
                           <Comment.Text>{serviceNote.entry}</Comment.Text>
                              :
                            <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                                <Form.Input value={serviceNote.entry} name="entry" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                </Form.Input>
                                    <Button type="submit" size="small">Update</Button>
                                </Form>
                             }
                         </Table.Cell>
                       </Table.Row>
                     </Comment.Content>
                   ))}
                   <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                     <Form.TextArea
                       style={{ height: "50px" }}
                       onChange={this.handleChange}
                       name="entry"
                       value={this.state.entry}
                     />
                     <Form.Button
                       type="submit"
                       content="Add Note"
                       labelPosition="left"
                       icon="edit"
                       primary
                     />
                   </Form>
                 </Comment.Group>
               </Comment>
             </Table.Body>
           </Table>
         </div>
       </>
     );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    services: state.services.services,
    notes: state.notes.notes
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
       createNote: (entry, serviceId, userId) => dispatch(createNote(entry, serviceId, userId)) 
       
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ServiceLogsComponent);
```

I'm also having trouble with `onChange` when editing text. It doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You have one state flag "showInput" that is shared by all of your notes, therefore when you turn it on, all of your notes go to edit mode.

In this line:

```
<Form.Input value={serviceNote.entry} name="entry" onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

The value is not updated as a result of onChange, value should be assigned to something from the state that has been updated by onChange

You should create a child component to display one note, so that each note can have its own showInput flag and value to display.

Comment: Ok if I understand you, create something like `<EntryComponent entry={serviceNotes.entry} />` ? And this wouldn't be affected by the iteration?

Comment: Exactly, and you will create the EntryComponent with {this.filterNotes().map((serviceNote) => { return <EntryComponent...

Comment: I'm still confused about the difference between having the iteration in the parent component vs a child component. What's the difference? How do I escape the fact that there's still an iteration taking place no matter what the depth?

Comment: If you do the iteration in the parent, then each child will have it's one showInput flag and value. So each input will act independently of the other ones

Comment: But would there be a separate iteration for when input is revealed? Sorry, I still don't understand what goes into the new component.

Comment: Basically the whole <Comment.Content> could be moved to a Comment component